# Loop through "selected" Enum values?

Tags: c#

I know how to loop through enum list of properties, but how would I loop through all "selected" enum properties? For example, if one did `Prop1 | Prop2` against `public enum Foo { Prop1; Prop2; Prop3 }`, how would I achieve this?

This is what I have now:

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FileStatus)).Cast<FileStatus>();
foreach (var value in values)
{
}
```

It loops through all enum properties, but I'd like to loop only the ones that were "selected".

Update: `[Flags]` attribute was set.

Update 2: The enum contains a large number of properties, I can't and won't type/hardcode a single property check, instead I want to dynamically loop through each of them and check if my enum instance `Bar` contains the looped item set.

Comment: Did you stick the FlagsAttribute on the enum?

Comment: @Hexxagonal: Doesn't matter.  However, explicitly assigning values matters a whole lot.

Comment: @Hexxagonal That's really more optional than anything.  The enums may or may not each be powers of two. Whether or not the flags att. is set *should* matter, but really it doesn't.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325659/closing-for-duplicate).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about the following:

```
FileStatus status = FileStatus.New|FileStatus.Amazing;

foreach (FileStatus x in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FileStatus)))
{
    if (status.HasFlag(x)) Console.WriteLine("{0} set", x);
}
```

Or in one fell LINQ swoop:

```
var flags = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FileStatus))
                .Cast<FileStatus>()
                .Where(s => status.HasFlag(s));
```

Comment: +1, I agree, it only prints if the flag is set.

Comment: Works wonderfully! `if` passes only when the looped enum property is set for the status!

Answer (score 4):

```
[Flags]
public enum Foo
{
    Prop1 = 1,
    Prop2 = 1 << 1,
    Prop3 = 1 << 2
}

public static class FooExtensions
{
    private static readonly Foo[] values = (Foo[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foo));

    public static IEnumerable<Foo> GetComponents(this Foo value)
    {
        return values.Where(v => (v & value) != 0);
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = Foo.Prop1 | Foo.Prop3;

        var components = foo.GetComponents().ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have this set as a bitmask, then simply "and"-ing the values would determine which are selected.

```
 SomeEnum bitmask = value;

 if(bitmask & SomeEnum.Value1 > 0)
    // SomeEnum.Value1 was set
```

Comment: `bitmask.HasFlag(SomeEnum.Value1)` is more readable and does the same thing

Comment: Good point! Still, it's nice to understand exactly what that is doing under the hood, for completeness sake.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileStatus someValue = ...;
var selectedValues = new List<FileStatus>();
var allValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FileStatus)).Cast<FileStatus>();
foreach (var value in allValues )
{
  if(someValue & value != 0)//note bitwise AND, not logical AND.
  {
     selectedValues.Add(value);
     //this value is selected.  You can stick it in a List or do whatever with it.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to mark the enum with `Flags` attribute. To get the values you can use `yourObject.EnumProperty.HasFlag` method, for example:

```
class Program 
{
    [Flags]
    public enum Bar { Prop1, Prop2, Prop3 }

    public class Foo
    {
        public Bar SelectedBar { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.SelectedBar = Bar.Prop1 | Bar.Prop2;

        foo.SelectedBar.HasFlag(Bar.Prop1); //true
        foo.SelectedBar.HasFlag(Bar.Prop2); //true
        foo.SelectedBar.HasFlag(Bar.Prop3); //false
    }
}
```